How can I update display of chat history upon page refresh?
My chat UI using Gradio:
import sqlite3
import gradio as gr
import time

formatted_history = []
sqlite = None

def loadHistoryFromDB():
    global sqlite,formatted_history

    sql="SELECT role,message from chat_history order by created_at_unix ASC Limit 10";
    cur = sqlite.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        formatted_history.append({
            'role':row[0],
            'content':row[1]
        })

def chatHandler(message,history,generate_image):
    sql = "INSERT INTO chat_history (role, message, created_at_unix) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    current_unix_time = int(time.time())  # Get the current Unix timestamp

    response = f"Hello {message}"

    sqlite.execute(sql, ('user', message, int(time.time())))
    time.sleep(3)
    sqlite.execute(sql, ('assistant', response, int(time.time())))
    sqlite.commit()

    yield response

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sqlite = sqlite3.connect("chat_history.db",check_same_thread=False)
    loadHistoryFromDB()

    with gr.Blocks() as demo:
        chatbot = gr.Chatbot(type="messages", value=formatted_history)
        chat = gr.ChatInterface(chatHandler,type="messages",chatbot=chatbot)

    demo.launch()

I use sqlite3 to store chat history. But a page refresh fails to retrieve recently sent messages. I only get the ones already fetched from database.
The bug occurs when:

I launch my python script.
I visit page indicated by Gradio.
I place a message.
I then refresh the page.

How can I show recently sent messages on page refresh and not only history already loaded? I tried:
import sqlite3
import gradio as gr
import time

formatted_history = []
sqlite = None

def loadHistoryFromDB():
    global sqlite,formatted_history

    sql="SELECT role,message from chat_history order by created_at_unix ASC Limit 10";
    cur = sqlite.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        formatted_history.append({
            'role':row[0],
            'content':row[1]
        })

def chatHandler(message,history,generate_image):
    sql = "INSERT INTO chat_history (role, message, created_at_unix) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    current_unix_time = int(time.time())  # Get the current Unix timestamp

    response = f"Hello {message}"
    history.append({"role":'user','content':message})
    sqlite.execute(sql, ('user', message, int(time.time())))
    time.sleep(3)
    history.append({"role":'assistant','content':response})
    sqlite.execute(sql, ('assistant', response, int(time.time())))
    sqlite.commit()

    yield response

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sqlite = sqlite3.connect("chat_history.db",check_same_thread=False)
    loadHistoryFromDB()

    with gr.Blocks() as demo:
        chatbot = gr.Chatbot(type="messages", value=formatted_history)
        chat = gr.ChatInterface(chatHandler,type="messages",chatbot=chatbot)

    demo.launch()

But I still fail to load the most recent chat history upon refresh.

But I do sqlite.commit() at chatHandler. Any message must be returned or yielded.

The solution is to turn formatted_history into a state. In order to do this is to use demo.load at your code and set as output the chatbot element.
The final example is:
import sqlite3
import gradio as gr
import time

formatted_history = []
sqlite = None


def loadHistoryFromDB():
    """Fetch the latest 10 messages from the database and populate `formatted_history`."""
    global sqlite, formatted_history

    sql = "SELECT role, message FROM chat_history ORDER BY created_at_unix ASC LIMIT 10"
    cur = sqlite.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        formatted_history.append({
            'role': row[0],
            'content': row[1]
        })


def chatHandler(message, history):
    global sqlite,formatted_history
    """Handle new messages and update chat history in the database and UI."""
    sql = "INSERT INTO chat_history (role, message, created_at_unix) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    current_unix_time = int(time.time())  # Get the current Unix timestamp

    # Save user's message to the database
    sqlite.execute(sql, ('user', message, current_unix_time))
    formatted_history.append({"role":"user","content":message})
    # Generate the assistant's response
    response = f"Hello {message}"

    # Save assistant's response to the database
    sqlite.execute(sql, ('assistant', response, int(time.time())))
    formatted_history.append({"role":"assistant","content":response})
    sqlite.commit()

    yield response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize the database connection
    sqlite = sqlite3.connect("chat_history.db", check_same_thread=False)

    # Load initial chat history
    loadHistoryFromDB()

    # Set up the Gradio interface
    with gr.Blocks() as demo:
        chatbot = gr.Chatbot(type="messages", value=formatted_history)
        chat = gr.ChatInterface(fn=chatHandler, type="messages", chatbot=chatbot)
        demo.load(lambda :formatted_history,None,chatbot)

    # Launch the application
    demo.launch()

First and foremost pay attention at:
    with gr.Blocks() as demo:
        chatbot = gr.Chatbot(type="messages", value=formatted_history)
        chat = gr.ChatInterface(fn=chatHandler, type="messages", chatbot=chatbot)
        demo.load(lambda :formatted_history,None,chatbot)

As explained above, I set the chatbot as output of the whatever I store upon formatted_history. Another way you should pay attention is in the function chatHandler In that we append the nessesary messages into formatted_history:
def chatHandler(message, history):
    global sqlite,formatted_history
    """Handle new messages and update chat history in the database and UI."""
    sql = "INSERT INTO chat_history (role, message, created_at_unix) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    current_unix_time = int(time.time())  # Get the current Unix timestamp

    sqlite.execute(sql, ('user', message, current_unix_time))
    
    # Append Value upon `formatted_history` in order to update the state
    formatted_history.append({"role":"user","content":message})

    # Generate the assistant's response
    response = f"Hello {message}"

    sqlite.execute(sql, ('assistant', response, int(time.time())))

    # Append Value upon `formatted_history` in order to update the state
    formatted_history.append({"role":"assistant","content":response})
    sqlite.commit()

    yield response

